# the Cobain estate tapped Morgen

Tags: meaning

Here is the sentence:

> Courtney Love and **the Cobain estate tapped Morgen** to make a film examining the life of the late Nirvana frontman, and the project has started to come together after five years of planning.

I am not sure whether I understand to the emphasized part of the sentence. Will somebody help me? Does it mean that Cobain’s items from legacy have inspired the director?

Answer (score 10):

*The Cobain estate* is the legal entity that remains of Kurt Cobain’s assets, mostly represented by lawyers, I presume.

*Tap* in this sense [(ODO article, sense 3)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tap#tap-2) is to:

> Designate or select (someone) for a task or honour, especially membership of an organization or committee

In other words, Courtney Love and the lawyers that represent Kurt Cobain’s estate jointly *selected* Morgen to the director to make the film in question.

Comment: It's very common. For example, this one, from near the top of a google search for "tapped for project": [Starchitect Norman Foster tapped for Transbay mixed-use project](http://www.bizjournals.com/sanfrancisco/blog/real-estate/2014/03/starchitect-norman-foster-tapped-for-transbay.html)

Comment: I’ve heard it before, but I wouldn’t say it’s “very common” in my experience either. Perhaps I just don’t move in fancy enough circles.

Comment: It's very common in the US. I never stopped to think of the origin, but have always had a mental image of *tapping a tree* or *putting a tap in them* to draw on their experience. Now I might need to investigate the etymology of this use. :/

Comment: @medica, I suspect it does derive from _tapping a tree_. The meaning is similar.

Comment: I'd always assumed (no evidence) that the origin was related to games where you physically tap the next person to be 'It' , like in tag.

Comment: This usage seems to be rare outside of the New York Times and certain other US media.

Comment: I suspect (but don't have sources) that it's closer to @Karen's suggestion. Many secret societies and whatnot tap someone on the shoulder in rites to let them know they're "in" or have been selected for something.

Comment: From my somewhat limited exposure to the term, I have also always imagined it as being from the action of tapping someone on the shoulder, similar to how you can now _tag_ someone to do something.